# How can I load the array images from JSON file in react gatsby?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby, gatsby-image

I'm working with react gatsby, I'm creating pages from JSON file that looks like this

```
    [
    {
        "slug": "camping",
        "img": "../assets/images/campingDetails.jpg",
        "name": "Camping",
        "description": "Acampada, campismo,​ campamento o el anglicismo camping​ hacen referencia a la actividad humana que consiste en colocar una vivienda temporal, ya sea portátil o improvisada, en un lugar con el fin de habitarla. También se denomina así al lugar físico donde se realiza esta actividad.",
        "gallery" : [
                {"imageC": "../assets/images/campingDetails.jpg"} ,
                {"imageC": "../assets/images/camping1.jpg"}
        ]
    },

    {
        "slug": "pesca",
        "img": "../assets/images/FishingDetails.jpg",
        "name": "Pesca",
        "description": "La pesca se define como aquella actividad que se realiza para extraer peces. Puede realizarse en aguas continentales o marítimas. Ancestralmente, la pesca ha consistido en una de las actividades económicas más tempranas de muchos pueblos del mundo.",
        "gallery" : [
            {"imageC": "../assets/images/FishingDetails.jpg"} ,
            {"imageC": "../assets/images/pesca1.jpg"}
    ]
        
    },

    {
        "slug": "andinismo",
        "img": "../assets/images/climbingDetails.jpg",
        "name": "Andinismo",
        "description": "El montañismo nace en los Alpes al final del siglo XVIII. Su objetivo es conseguir llegar a la cima de una determinada montaña, como un reto a la naturaleza, que en ocasiones se llega a perder la vida..",
        "gallery" : [
            {"imageC": "../assets/images/climbingDetails.jpg"} ,
            {"imageC": "../assets/images/andinismo1.jpg"}
    ]
    },

    {
        "slug": "senderismo",
        "img": "../assets/images/senderismoDetails.jpg",
        "name": "Senderismo",
        "descritcioncion": "El senderismo es una actividad deportiva no competitiva que consiste en caminar siguiendo un itinerario determinado. Se acostumbra a realizar en senderos balizados y homologados por el organismo competente de cada país, pero también por sendas, caminos rurales y vías verdes sin homologar.",
        "gallery" : [
            {"imageC": "../assets/images/senderismoDetails.jpg"} ,
            {"imageC": "../assets/images/senderismo1.jpg"}
    ]
    },

    {
        "slug": "montaña",
        "img": "../assets/images/montanaDetails.jpg",
        "name": "Montaña",
        "description": "El montañismo es el deporte de caminar y hacer excursiones por las montañas. A diferencia del senderismo, que se realiza normalmente por senderos señalizados, y el trekking, una travesía de varios de días por entornos lejanos, el montañismo tiene como motivación el destino, la montaña, y por rutas de más dificultad.",
        "gallery" : [
            {"imageC": "../assets/images/montanaDetails.jpg"} ,
            {"imageC": "../assets/images/montana1.jpg"}
    ]
    }

]
```

I am creating the pages based on the slug, that is, the page is created and the information is loaded according to the slug, that is, I show the name and description and the background image, that works correctly. What I need and cannot find a solution is to add the images found in the gallery in each of the objects. Any ideas please? I've been at this for a while and I can't.

This is my graphql query:

```
    query MyQuery { detailsCategoriesJson(slug: {eq: "camping"}) {
    name
    description
    img {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        }
      }
    }
    gallery {
      imageC {
        childImageSharp {
          fluid {
                        ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
          }
        }
      }
    } 
   } 
  }
```

and these are the results of the query:

```
    {"data": {
    "detailsCategoriesJson": {
      "name": "Camping",
      "description": "Acampada, campismo,​ campamento o el anglicismo camping​ hacen referencia a la actividad humana que consiste en colocar una vivienda temporal, ya sea portátil o improvisada, en un lugar con el fin de habitarla. También se denomina así al lugar físico donde se realiza esta actividad.",
      "img": {
        "childImageSharp": {
          "fluid": {
            "base64": "data:image/jpeg;base64,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",
            "aspectRatio": 1.5037593984962405,
            "src": "/static/6f5238b594b0fea47a09ebed51647672/14b42/campingDetails.jpg",
            "srcSet": "/static/6f5238b594b0fea47a09ebed51647672/f836f/campingDetails.jpg 200w,\n/static/6f5238b594b0fea47a09ebed51647672/2244e/campingDetails.jpg 400w,\n/static/6f5238b594b0fea47a09ebed51647672/14b42/campingDetails.jpg 800w,\n/static/6f5238b594b0fea47a09ebed51647672/47498/campingDetails.jpg 1200w,\n/static/6f5238b594b0fea47a09ebed51647672/ec6c5/campingDetails.jpg 1280w",
            "sizes": "(max-width: 800px) 100vw, 800px"
          }
        }
      },
      "gallery": [
        {
          "imageC": {
            "childImageSharp": {
              "fluid": {
                "base64": "data:image/jpeg;base64,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",
                "aspectRatio": 1.5037593984962405,
                "src": "/static/6f5238b594b0fea47a09ebed51647672/14b42/campingDetails.jpg",
                "srcSet": "/static/6f5238b594b0fea47a09ebed51647672/f836f/campingDetails.jpg 200w,\n/static/6f5238b594b0fea47a09ebed51647672/2244e/campingDetails.jpg 400w,\n/static/6f5238b594b0fea47a09ebed51647672/14b42/campingDetails.jpg 800w,\n/static/6f5238b594b0fea47a09ebed51647672/47498/campingDetails.jpg 1200w,\n/static/6f5238b594b0fea47a09ebed51647672/ec6c5/campingDetails.jpg 1280w",
                "sizes": "(max-width: 800px) 100vw, 800px"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "imageC": {
            "childImageSharp": {
              "fluid": {
                "base64": "data:image/jpeg;base64,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",
                "aspectRatio": 0.6666666666666666,
                "src": "/static/e0827cd521be0a645fa77fa6a899e0dc/14b42/camping1.jpg",
                "srcSet": "/static/e0827cd521be0a645fa77fa6a899e0dc/f836f/camping1.jpg 200w,\n/static/e0827cd521be0a645fa77fa6a899e0dc/2244e/camping1.jpg 400w,\n/static/e0827cd521be0a645fa77fa6a899e0dc/14b42/camping1.jpg 800w,\n/static/e0827cd521be0a645fa77fa6a899e0dc/47498/camping1.jpg 1200w,\n/static/e0827cd521be0a645fa77fa6a899e0dc/ec6c5/camping1.jpg 1280w",
                "sizes": "(max-width: 800px) 100vw, 800px"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },  
"extensions": {}  
}
```

Este es mi archivo componente.js

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import Button from '../components/Button'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';
import Image from 'gatsby-image';


export const query = graphql`
  query ($slug : String! ) {
    detailsCategoriesJson(slug: {eq: $slug}) {
      name
      description
      img {
        childImageSharp {
          fluid {
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
          }
        }
      }
      gallery {
        imageC {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;


const templateDetalleCat = ({data}) => {

    const tD = data.detailsCategoriesJson;

    return (
        <Layout>
          <TemplateContainer>
            <TemplateBg>
            <Image 
              fluid={tD.img.childImageSharp.fluid}
              alt={tD.name}
            /> 
            </TemplateBg>
                <TemplateContent>
                    <TemplateItems>
                      <TemplateH1> {tD.name} </TemplateH1>
                      <TemplateP>{tD.description}</TemplateP>
                      <Button primary="true" big="true" round="true" to="/tienda">Shop now</Button>
                    </TemplateItems>
                </TemplateContent>
                
          </TemplateContainer>
          <CarContainer>

          </CarContainer>
        </Layout>  
    )
}

export default templateDetalleCat
```

I'm triying to show the images from gallery but i don't know how, I'm tried a few things but I can´t. Any ideas? Thank you
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your queries work as expected, you only need to access the images array in `data` and loop through them:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import Button from '../components/Button'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';
import Image from 'gatsby-image';


export const query = graphql`
  query ($slug : String! ) {
    detailsCategoriesJson(slug: {eq: $slug}) {
      name
      description
      img {
        childImageSharp {
          fluid {
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
          }
        }
      }
      gallery {
        imageC {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;


const templateDetalleCat = ({data}) => {

    const tD = data.detailsCategoriesJson;

    return (
        <Layout>
          <TemplateContainer>
            <TemplateBg>
            <Image 
              fluid={tD.img.childImageSharp.fluid}
              alt={tD.name}
            /> 
            </TemplateBg>
                <TemplateContent>
                    <TemplateItems>
                      <TemplateH1> {tD.name} </TemplateH1>
                      <TemplateP>{tD.description}</TemplateP>
                      <Button primary="true" big="true" round="true" to="/tienda">Shop now</Button>
                    </TemplateItems>
                </TemplateContent>    
              {tD.gallery.map(image=>{

               return <Img fluid={image.imageC.childImageSharp.fluid} />
             })}
          </TemplateContainer>
          <CarContainer>

          </CarContainer>
        </Layout>  
    )
}

export default templateDetalleCat
```

Your array of images are inside `data.detailsCategoriesJson.gallery` (array), so you only need to loop through them and display the images using the  tag:

```
  {tD.gallery.map(image=>{

   return <Img fluid={image.imageC.childImageSharp.fluid} />
 })}
```

Comment: thank you @Ferran, yes the results of my query return the information based on the slug, and yes that's my problem I need to acces to the gallery and loop through them. I already do it what you suggest me and I get this error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't saw your destructuring. Should be `tD.gallery.map`

Comment: Thank you so much @Ferran.! It worked so good..!! Thank you.! I've been like a week trying to resolve this...I'm just starting in this world

Comment: It has been a pleasure :) If the issue has been solved please consider accept/upvoting it. Que vaya muy bien!